# UIImagePicker is being obstructed by UITabBar

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, uitabbar

I have created a Tabbar app where my Uitabbar is located in the app delegate. I am displaying a UIImagePicker and enabling the camera using iPhone SDK 3.0. How can I get the camera to:
1. Resize to smaller height above the tab bar.
2. Effectively hide the UITabbar so camera button shows up on bottom.

I have tried many things that have been posted, but with no success. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are utilising the built in toolbar of the navigationController.  You can do something like this:

[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden: TRUE];

You need to set it to FALSE for when you DO want it visible of course.

Comment: Please flag this as the correct answer: this place is give and take.